# Table of content in beamer stays empty

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm trying to get a table of content in my slides. I've found a minimal example here on the site:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide1}
slide 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am using Mac and the terminal command pdflatex. If I do this the result is a pdf with two slides, but the first one stays empty.

Comment: do you compile twice? your example works fine ...

Comment: What?! If I compile it twice, the toc appears.. What's the reason for that?

Comment: The first time it doesn't know when certain things are. This could be the case for indices, references, a certain type of figures, etc.. in these case you need to compile more than one time. if you look at the log file it is written if the file should be recompiled.

Comment: @Zarko, I don't think to be good enough in TeX to write a good answer in this topic. There are too many packages and commands that requires the double compilation and I don't know all of them and if the cause is always the same.